# I want to use the action view once we click on a video in the webview. which method do I use the action view in it?

Tags: java, video, view, android-webview

I want to show a view(Action_View) that asks me to choose an app to play the video.

*video= in my webview browser.*
Now I can use the implicit intent to show the apps that can perform the action, however, I don't know in which method I put my implicit intent.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow, please provide more information or a code example that you are trying

Comment: I have edited my query. unfortunately, I can't upload images.